# how to create a flex program that passes the text input to servlet and redirects to same servlet

Tags: java, apache-flex, servlets

I want to redirect mxml file to servlet and print the code on servlet but when i use navigate to url code then the output shows **null** values of the textinput fields in the servlet page, please help me clerify the problem the basic coding of mxml and servlet are given below

**The MXML File**

```
<s:Application...>
<fx:Script>
<![CDATA[
  import flash.net.navigateToURL;
  import mx.controls.*;
  import mx.events.Request;
  import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
  import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;

  public function resultHandler(event : ResultEvent):void
  {             
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest('Srvlt'),'_self')
  }
  public function faultHandler(event : FaultEvent):void
  {
    Alert.show("error");
  }
]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
  <s:HTTPService id="service" url="Srvlt" result="resultHandler(event)" fault="faultHandler(event)" method="GET" showBusyCursor="true" resultFormat="text">
    <s:request xmlns="">
      <email>{email.text}</email>
      <pass>{pass.text}</pass>
    </s:request>
  </s:HTTPService>
</fx:Declarations>
<s:VGroup verticalAlign="middle">
  <s:FormItem label="E-mail : ">
    <s:TextInput id="email" />
  </s:FormItem>
  <s:FormItem label="Password :">
    <s:TextInput id="pass" displayAsPassword="true" />
  </s:FormItem>
  <mx:Button label="Submit" click="service.send()" />
</s:VGroup>
</s:Application>
```

**The servlet's get method coding is as follows**

```
String e = request.getParameter("email");
String p = request.getParameter("pass");
String resul;
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
resul = "Hi i am servlet, your username is " + e + " & password is " + p + ". are they correct ?";
out.print(resul);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're sending 2 different requests in your application. The first one is `HTTPService`, the second one is `URLRequest`.

```
<s:HTTPService id="service" url="Srvlt" result="resultHandler(event)"
fault="faultHandler(event)" method="GET" showBusyCursor="true" resultFormat="text">
    <s:request xmlns="">
        <email>{email.text}</email>
        <pass>{pass.text}</pass>
    </s:request>
</s:HTTPService>
```

When you handle result, you can get your response string via `ResultEvent` object

```
public function resultHandler(event : ResultEvent):void
{
    Alert.show(event.result); // you'll see "Hi i am servlet..." here
}
```

You can work now with this string.

But if you want to open new page with the result text, then you don't need to use `HTTPService`. Use `URLRequest` class.

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("Srvlt");
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
variables.email = email.text;
variables.pass = pass.text;
request.data = variables;
navigateToURL(request);
```

So, you're doing it wrong now. Don't send 2 requests. Choose either `HTTPService` and handling result inside the application, or `navigateToURL` and `URLRequest` if you want just to display response in new window.

Comment: where would i be required to put the above given code? how would i call the function.. and thanks a lot

Comment: @Karan if you decided to use URLRequest, then just wrap those code lines into function and call it on button click

Comment: thanks a lot Timofei, i appreciate for such a great response of yours for my request... :-) thanks a lot for rectifying the issue.. and would give you pain for asking few more questions in coming days

Comment: @Karan you're welcome :) P.s. To format the code, select it all and format (not line by line)

Comment: and one more thing could you tell me the best source to learn flex with the perspective of integrating it with java..

Comment: @Karan if you're new to actionscript - http://www.amazon.com/Essential-ActionScript-3-0-Colin-Moock/dp/0596526946 ; Flex 4 - http://www.amazon.com/Flash-Builder-Flex-Bible-Wiley/dp/0470488956 ; BlazeDS (flex+java integrating) http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/blazeds_devguide.pdf

Comment: @Karan you can also learn adobe documantations (no need of flex 4 book then) http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/index.html

Comment: hey Timofei could you please tell me a way to pass data from the servlet to flex page. for example passing on the String e to some other flex(mxml) file.

Comment: @Karan the answer is here. Read it attentively :) You get the string in resultHandler

Comment: Timofei I want a way to redirect the data which is present in a jsp to a flex page, how to do that?